# Greenlet runtime error and deployed app in docker keeps booting all the workers

Tags: python, azure-devops, devops, gevent, greenlets

> RuntimeWarning: greenlet.greenlet size changed, may indicate binary
> incompatibility. Expected 144 from C header, got 152 from PyObject

And all the workers are being booted.

> 2020-09-28T14:09:41.864089908Z [2020-09-28 14:09:41 +0000] [31] [INFO]
> Booting worker with pid: 31 2020-09-28T14:09:43.933141974Z [2020-09-28
> 14:09:43 +0000] [32] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32
> 2020-09-28T14:09:44.317436676Z [2020-09-28 14:09:44 +0000] [33] [INFO]
> Booting worker with pid: 33 2020-09-28T14:09:44.795236476Z [2020-09-28
> 14:09:44 +0000] [34] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 34

It was working fine a week back or so and now I'm starting to have the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

as https://discuss.redash.io/t/binary-compatibility-issue-with-greenlet/7237
indicates
a workaround is greenlet==0.4.16 or upgrade your gevent to 20.9.0

following fix is suggested on the greenlet github page

https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/178#issuecomment-697342964

also see following issues

- https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/180
- https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/182
- https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/178

Comment: This worked. Installing greenlet < 1.0 is discouraged. Probably, gevent version is outdated -- upgrading `gevent` will most likely to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the combination that worked for me, as I was getting this error on Mac OS 13[M1(ARM)], if your env is other than this the latest version of Greenlet will work.

give it a try for Mac (ARM)

```
gevent==21.8.0
greenlet==1.1.3
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Comment: This worked for me. Even just `gevent==21.8.0` is enough to fix the problem in Mac/ARM. Thanks @Madhav Mansuriya!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved with [gevent](https://pypi.org/project/gevent/) version 22.10.2 with [greenlet](https://pypi.org/project/greenlet/) version 2.0.1

Comment: latest version of greenlet is 2.0.2

Comment: @teebszet thanks fixed version info for greenlet